# "Captcha" security question not showing in Firefox

Tags: firefox

You know these windows that pop up with "I am not a robot" on certain pages. All you have to do is click the box. I had to go to my wife's Mac to get into that page because all it showed here (Ubuntu 20.04, Firefox) was an empty window. What's the reason for that and how do I manage it?

Comment: I'd check your extensions & security settings; you can prevent that box from working by refusing to let code run from web sites (ie. security settings/extensions prevent it).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ublock or adblock installed? Adblocking extensions can block those. You can temporarily disable extensions and try again to see if it works. If issue persists, clearing the cache and cookies from the browser can help.